# Axios interceptor always resolves promise

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I am trying to intercept a axios post call in vue.

First I create the Axios in axios.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/` // the url of our server
})

Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance

export { axiosInstance }
```

Here you see the axios call and the interceptors

```
import { axiosInstance } from '../boot/axios'

export default {
  validateUsers: async (username, password) => {
    // var usersPromise = axiosInstance.post('/users', {
    axiosInstance.post('/users', {
      params: {
        name: username,
        password: password
      }
    })
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      console.log('RESPONSE', response)
      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log('You are not authorized')
        return Promise.reject(response)
      } else if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('response SUCC')
        return response
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('ERROR RECEIVED BY AXIOS', error.response)
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        return Promise.reject(error.response.status)
      }
      console.log('ERR RES', error.message)
      return Promise.reject(error.message)
    })
  }
}
```

And in my Vue component I check for the promise like this

```
usersAPI.validateUsers(username, password)
    .then(ok => {
      console.log('ok', ok)
      this.valForm(this.$refs.loginForm)
    }, (error) => {
      if (error === 401) {
        this.getMessage('error', 'User or password wrong')
        return error
      }
      this.getMessage('error', 'Something went wrong. Error: ' + error)
      return error
    })
```

In my nodeJS code I return a 401 if the user login is not correct and I can see that CORS first sends an OPTION call which returns 204 and then I send the 401 (which is correct).

**What I expect**

Axios interceptors handle the 401 error and reject the promise

**What happens**

The `validateUsers()` function returns 'ok' (promise is resolved) instead of rejected by axios.

Why is Axios not handling the 401 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should await your axios call and return the promise to make your code work.

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import axios from 'axios'

    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/` // the url of our server
    })

    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      console.log('RESPONSE', response)
      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log('You are not authorized')
        return Promise.reject(response)
      } else if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('response SUCC')
        return response
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('ERROR RECEIVED BY AXIOS', error.response)
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        return Promise.reject(error.response.status)
      }
      console.log('ERR RES', error.message)
      return Promise.reject(error.message)
    })

    Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance

    export { axiosInstance }
```

```
    import { axiosInstance } from '../boot/axios'

    export default {
      validateUsers: async (username, password) => {
        return axiosInstance.post('/users', {
          params: {
            name: username,
            password: password
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

And in your Vue component the promise should be resolved or rejected correctly.

```
    usersAPI.validateUsers(username, password)
        .then(ok => {
          console.log('ok', ok)
          this.valForm(this.$refs.loginForm)
        }, (error) => {
          if (error === 401) {
            this.getMessage('error', 'User or password wrong')
            return error
          }
          this.getMessage('error', 'Something went wrong. Error: ' + error)
          return error
        })
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. So does this mean I have to handle all Interceptions of all axios calls there? I thought I could create an interception per call.

Comment: @Toby You create one interceptor per axios instance. So if you need a different interceptor behavior, you need to create an other axios instance. Hope it is clear ? :)